# Bought a house, a/c not working, contract specifies a/c service, who is at fault?

Tags: united-states, real-estate, new-mexico

I bought a house in New Mexico that closed about 2 months ago.  According to the contract, the sellers agreed to have the a/c unit serviced.  Exact words "seller agrees to have the a/c unit serviced by a licensed hvac technician".  I did not receive a receipt for this service.  I get into the house after closing and the a/c unit is working.  6 weeks later it is not.  An hvac tech arrives to tell me that the a/c unit hasn't been touched in years.  Ergo, the sellers did not have the a/c unit serviced.  Or, if they did, they did not share the results with me, the buyer.  Is there anything I can do?  Or is there even someone I can yell at?  I did not insist on a receipt for this service so maybe it's on me?  Or on the sellers?  On my realtor?

Thanks very much

Comment: There is nothing you can do that will cost less than paying to service the AC yourself.  It is annoying, but that is the way the cookie crumbles sometimes.

Comment: I'm flagging this question as off-topic because it is about the specifics of your contract and your recourse to the alleged failure of the selling party to honour the contract, therefore this question is better suited for the Law Stack Exchange. You should contact a lawyer to determine what your options are regarding your situation.

Comment: Even if the seller is at fault (which in my opinion, they are not), how do you expect them to pay for anything? You can sue them, but court is expensive... It may be best to just deal with this yourself and take the lesson. Get receipts next time.

Comment: @Nosjack The first step is just to contact the seller and make a request for what the OP believes they are owed - if they agree to it, there is no need to involve a court. I don't see why they wouldn't held to the contract terms. There might be an argument that they only owe the cost of a service appointment and not a repair, but they clearly violated the contract if it indeed stipulated a service that never happened.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments.  I'm sorry that I asked this in the wrong forum!

Answer (score 1):

Thank-you to the commenters. The answer is that this is on me.  I can be annoyed that the sellers did not have the a/c unit serviced but there is little reason to pursue it as it would be more trouble than it's worth.